# How can i transform the dataset using pivot table?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to transform my dataset such way:

Input:

| id | drug1_drug | drug2_drug | drug3_drug | age |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 33 |
| 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 33 |
| 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 33 |
| 2 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 45 |
| 2 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 45 |
| 3 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 66 |
| 3 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 66 |
| 3 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 66 |
| 4 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 28 |
| 4 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 28 |
| 5 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 87 |
| 5 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 87 |

Output:

| id | age | therapy |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 33 | drug2 |
| 2 | 45 | drug2,drug3 |
| 3 | 66 | drug1,drug2 |
| 4 | 28 | drug1,drug3 |
| 5 | 87 | drug1 |

Column names with _drug are constant for a particular id. And i need if it '1' put the name of the drug to the new table. Iam not so good at pandas, but i understand that we need to use `pivot_table`, but in what way i really dont know. I would be very grateful for answering my questions!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, use:

```
(df.set_index(['id', 'age'])
   .rename(columns=lambda x: x.replace('_drug', ''))
   .replace(0, float('nan'))
   .stack()
   .reset_index()
   .groupby(['id', 'age'], as_index=False)
   .agg(therapy=('level_2', lambda x: ','.join(dict.fromkeys(x))))
)
```

output:

```
   id  age      therapy
0   1   33        drug2
1   2   45  drug2,drug3
2   3   66  drug1,drug2
3   4   28  drug1,drug3
4   5   87        drug1
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's try

```py
out = (df.drop_duplicates(df.columns)
       .melt(id_vars=['id', 'age'], var_name='therapy')
       .query('value == 1')
       .drop(columns='value')
       .pipe(lambda d: d.assign(therapy=d['therapy'].str.rstrip('_drug')))
       .groupby(['id', 'age'], as_index=False)['therapy']
       .agg(','.join))
```

```
print(out)

   id  age      therapy
0   1   33        drug2
1   2   45  drug2,drug3
2   3   66  drug1,drug2
3   4   28  drug1,drug3
4   5   87        drug1
```